# How do I correctly backup data before fresh install?

Tags: partitioning, backup, home-directory, reinstall

I recently messed my box and want to install everything fresh. I currently have access to the hard disk through the live CD.

I have my home folder which is what contains everything I need in the new system. However, I do not have a external HDD that I can use to backup.

This is the solution I can think of:

- I repartition a new partition in the internal HDD (currently there is just one) and copy my home files to that partition.
- I install the new OS in the old partition, completely wiping it.
- I then boot into the live CD again and copy back the home files to some directory in the freshly installed partition.
- Now I want to get the full size of the of hard disk. So I merge the two partitions (thereby keeping the fresh-install + copied home files, and delete the home files in the other partition).

Is this feasible? If so, how do I correctly do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Ehm #3 is not needed. You can mount the partition in the new OS.

Comment: You mean like a home partition?

Comment: No any partition not part of the current OS you can mount. "I install the new OS in the old partition, completely wiping it." when this is done you can mount "copy my home files to that partition." and copy the files from there over to the new OS so you do not need "I then boot into the live CD again and copy back the home files to some directory in the freshly installed partition."

Comment: Oh and this is easier when you use an external disk ;-) Then you can just do #1 and copy the files from the external disk. No need for partitioning or merging